# How do I set nested object entries coming from an api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js, object

I got an object where I keep track of several things that the user can fill out, delete, update, etc.

Now, when 'loading' such a project, I make an api call to my backend using axios to retrieve the specific data to send it back to the client. The api call looks like this:

```
axios.get(`/api/data/${this.$route.params.dataId}`)
  .then((response) => {

    //Why does this not work?
    this.nestedObject = response.data.object

    //This DOES work... Why?
    this.nestedObject.recipes = response.data.object.recipes
    this.nestedObject.cheffs= response.data.object.cheffs
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("error retrieving data: ", err);
  });
```

Whenever I just set `this.nestedObject` equal to the data that is coming from the server, it does not work. `nestedObject` is not updated with the new values. But when I set the individual entries in the object equal to the data that is coming from the server, it ***does*** work and `nestedObject` is updated appropriately. Why is that?

Comment: what is the initial value of nestedObject?

Comment: it is preloaded with the exact same data structure that is coming from the server. So in my example it already has a `.recipes` and `.cheffs` entry. I just want to update those.

Comment: try using `this.nestedObject = {...response.data.object}`